# How to tween Linear Velocity in rigidbody2d godot

Tags: godot, tween

**trying this code but it moves object diagonally(down-right)**

````
func _ready():
    tween = get_node("Tween")
    pass

func _physics_process(_delta):
    tween.interpolate_property(self,"linear_velocity",null,Vector2(0,0.1),1,Tween.TRANS_LINEAR,Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)
    tween.start()
    pass```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish and with which types of Node, however you can try something like this:

```
var TARGET_VELOCITY = Vector2(0,0.1)
var LERP_SPEED = 1

func _physics_process(_delta):
    var newVelocity = self.linear_velocity.linear_interpolate(TARGET_VELOCITY , delta * LERP_SPEED)
    self.linear_velocity = newVelocity
```

From the interpolation tutorial:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/interpolation.html

Comment: Sorry, My Value is too small ```tween.interpolate_property(self,"linear_velocity",null,Vector2(100,0),1,Tween.TRANS_LINEAR,Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)```& godot using my old code from vs code even after saving that's why it moving diagonally